# Is $(\mathbb{R}^n,P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}))$ a complete manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a basic question of Riemannian Geometry.

I am reading John Lee's book, and I found that $(\mathbb{R}^n,P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}))$ is isometric to $\mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{p\}$, where $P$ is the inverse map of the stereographic projection, that means,
$$P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}) = \frac{4}{(1+|x|^2)^2}(dx_1^2+\cdots+dx_n^2).$$

By the Classification theorem of simply-connected space forms, we have that a complete simply-connected Riemannian manifold with secctional curvature $1$ is globally isometric to $\mathbb{S}^n$. However $(\mathbb{R}^n,P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}))$ is a simply-connected Riemannian manifold with secctional curvature $1$ that is not isometric to  $\mathbb{S}^n$, since it is isometric to $\mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{p\}$. Therefore, $(\mathbb{R}^n,P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}))$ is not a complete manifold.

Can we prove that $(\mathbb{R}^n,P^*(d\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^n}))$ is not a complete manifold without mention to the stereographic projection?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you pullback a Riemannian metric by a diffeomorphism, the diffeomorphism automatically becomes an isometry. The reason you cannot apply the Classification Theorem, is that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not complete with the new metric, in the same way that the sphere minus one point is not complete, as they are isometric.

Comment: Thanks by your comment @Laz. But can we argue that $\mathbb{R}^n$ with this new metric is not complete without mention the stereographic projection? I will add this in the question.

Comment: You can use Hopf-Rinow Theorem, just notice that a geodesic through the origin "reaches infinity" in finite time $\pi$. However, this will irrevocably make reference to the stereographic projection, as you use it to define the metric.

Comment: Also, you can use a Cauchy sequence tending to infinity, I think that works since it will not converge. But again this speaks of distance, hence metric.

Comment: All you have to do is calculate the length of a ray from the origin to infinity.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your definition of complete. If you mean *geodesically* complete, then you can find a geodesic whose domain cannot be extended to $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, since this metric has rotational symmetry, all lines through the origin are geodesics when parameterized with constant speed. Solving the resulting differential equation shows that
$$
\gamma(t):=\left(\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right),0,\cdots,0\right)
$$
is a unit speed geodesic with domain $(-\pi,\pi)$. It cannot be continuously extended since $\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\tan(\theta)$ does not exist.

If you instead mean complete *as a metric space*, and you don't want to use Hopf-Rinow, then you can use $\gamma$ to define a Cauchy sequence that does not converge. (In this case, there's no need to even argue that $\gamma$ is a geodesic).

There are, of course, a number of other approaches corresponding to other characterizations of completeness.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Here, all of the different notions of completeness are equivalent.